# MySQL Workbench... Populating the fk column

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm brand new to MySQL Workbench and a have a bit of experience with databases (MS Access). I'm having trouble populating my fk with data. Here's what I have in my db schema:

- 2 tables Block and Set (Block having a pk Block_ID (type of INT); Set having fk to Block with fk name Set_Block_ID (type of INT).
- 1 to many relationship created from Block to Set tables linking Block_ID to Set_Block_ID. Relationship created, no problems
- I populate the Block table with data. No problems
- I then go to populate the Set table with data. I can see all my columns but not the fk. My question is why?

I have created the exact same db in MS Access and my fk is displayed in the linked table and I can populate it while MS Access makes sure referential integrity is enforced. I'm really brand new to Workbench and cant figure out why I cant see and populate my fk column.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!! =)

Answer (score 0):

After having digested all the replies to my question (note sarcasm here) I have finally found a workaround way of solving the issue.  To recap:

ISSUE:

- created a simple 2 table relationship with Workbench with PK and FK (1 .. n relationship)
- FK column not visible in Table Edit so not possible to enter any referencing data

SOLUTION:

- installed SQLyog and connected to same server
- opened same database and redid the simple 1 .. n relationship
- FK column visible for editing in SQLyog
- likewise, FK column visible for editing in Workbench

As I said, I'm new to this whole thing so I don't know what the problem was in Workbench. I just know it *seems* to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the relationship drawing tool does not create actual foreign key constraints.

However, if double-click the referencing table and switch to the foreign-key tab, you can create references and specify the columns involved. This generates and maintains the visual linkage automatically:

[image]